# Container element expand to the size of its position:absolute contents

Tags: html, css

In this markup:

```
<div id="A">
  <div id="B">
  </div>
</div>
```

if "#A" has position:relative and "#B" has position:absolute, it seems that "#A" wants to collapse to zero size, no matter the actual size of "#B".  How can I get "#A" to expand to the size of its contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that with CSS, you need JavaScript to set the `width` and `height` of the parent container(`#A`).

You could use `.offsetHeight` and `.offsetWidth`.

Both returns the actual `width`/`height` + `padding-left` and `padding-right`/`padding-top` and `padding-bottom` + `border-left-width` and `border-right-width`/ `border-top-width` and `border-bottom-width`.

---

In the example below, I've given the parent container(`#A`) a `backgroundImage` with `width` and `height` same as the child container and set the child container's(`#B`) `background`'s and `border`'s alpha value to `0.5`  to explain it better.

```js
var a = document.getElementById('A');
var b = document.getElementById('B');

a.style.height = b.offsetHeight + 'px';
a.style.width = b.offsetWidth + 'px';
a.style.backgroundImage = 'url(http://www.lorempixel.com/' + b.offsetWidth + '/' + b.offsetHeight + ')'
```

```css
#A {
  position: relative;
}
#B {
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(210,180,140, 0.5);
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 5px solid rgba(210,0,0, 0.5);
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="A">
  <div id="B">
  </div>
</div>
```

You could read more about this here: http://kingori.co/minutae/2013/05/relative-parent-absolute-children/

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping to avoid having to use javascript, but it does appear that it's the only way.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the display options ?

display: block

Could you present a more detailed version of your code ?